# Admob ad's cant be clicked most of the time

Tags: android, admob

I have a strange problem. The most of the times my ads cant be clicked on. The strange thing is that sometimes you can!!
if you cant click on the ad , then the logcat shows the following message:

```
W/Ads     (  477): Unable to check for AdMob redirect.
W/Ads     (  477): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /default2.aspx?lang=EN&gclid=CKa_39L4ua0CFWIntAod92Dc_Q
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
W/Ads     (  477):  at h$a.a(Unknown Source)
W/Ads     (  477):  at h$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
W/Ads     (  477):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
W/Ads     (  477):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Since the apps can sometimes be clicked , I dont think there is anything wrong with my code. But just to be sure:

```
public class Ad {
    private AdView adView;
    protected String id = MY_AD_ID;
    RelativeLayout adsLayout;
    public Ad(Window window,Context context) {  
        adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);      
        adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        adView = new AdView((Activity) context, AdSize.BANNER,id );  
        if(window != null) // to be clear this is needed for when I want to creat an ad in a AlertDialog ;)
            adsLayout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest newAdReq = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(newAdReq);
        if(window != null)
            window.addContentView(adsLayout,lp2);       
    }
    public AdView getAd() { 
        return adView;
    }
    public void newAd() {       
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return adView.getHeight();
    }
    public void removeView() {
        ((ViewGroup) adsLayout.getParent()).removeView(adView);
    }

}
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine.  Is this your own ad that you are trying to click?  It looks like the click url on the ad is wrong; if it is indeed `/default2.aspx?lang=EN&gclid=CKa_39L4ua0CFWIntAod92Dc_Q`, then it is not a valid web url, and is the source of the error.